# How can I chose random color from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've created a random number selecting system but I couldn't figure out how to pick it from the array please help me. Here is my code:

```
var buttonColours = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
var randomChosenColour = buttonColours[newSequence];

function newSequence () {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
}
```

Comment: Remember that functions in JavaScript do not return any value *unless* you have an explicit `return` statement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a random value from a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-a-random-value-from-a-javascript-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have extended your code with a function call and a `return` statement:

```js
var buttonColours = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
var randomChosenColour = buttonColours[newSequence()];

function newSequence () {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  
  return randomNumber;
}

console.log(randomChosenColour);
```

Or see a shorter version based on the suggestion:

```js
const buttonColours = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
const newSequence = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
const randomChosenColour = buttonColours[newSequence()];

console.log(randomChosenColour);
```

Comment: More minimally: `return Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);`

Comment: @tadman Agree, also extended my answer with my preference based on your suggestion.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `newSequence` to generate the number. and return the `randomNumber` from the function.

Like this:

```
var buttonColours = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
var randomChosenColour = buttonColours[newSequence()];

function newSequence () {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  return randomNumber;
}
```

There were two problems, the index selecting a value was not a number, it was a function (because the function was not being called), and secondly the function was creating a number but not returning it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This doesn't do anything, there's no return value.

Answer (score 1):

```
var randomColor=buttonColours[Math.floor(Math.random()*4)];
```

or, leaving room for expansion:

```
var randomColor=buttonColours[Math.floor(Math.random()*buttonColours.length)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Really all you need is a function to pick a random value, like [`_.sample`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#sample) from [Lodash](https://lodash.com/):

```
function sample(arr) {
   return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}
```

Where that can handle arbitrary arrays of arbitrary length:

```
sample(buttonColors);
```

Your `newSequence` function is way too specific and presumes a lot about the structure of the data. That `4` is a huge liability that needs to be removed.